# How can I know the starting address of data,stack and heap, and their sizes in memory for a C program process?

Tags: c, linux, process, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I know the starting address of data,stack and heap and their sizes in memory for a C program process in linux?

Comment: Is this an assignment question? I remember seeing the same one yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

I have included a couple code snippets to show how you determine the starting address and size of data stored on the heap and stack. I recommend you check out the links below to understand the examples better. Let me know if you have any other questions.

[Differences Between Stack and Heap](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm)

[Memory Layout of C Programs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

[Understanding Your Program's Memory](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understand-your-programs-memory-92431fa8c6b/)

#### Stack

```
int main() {
    // The following variables are stored on the stack
    int i = 4;
    char c = 'a';
    char s[6] = "Hello";

    // Starting addresses (use & operator)
    printf("Starting address of i = %p\n", &i);
    printf("Starting address of c = %p\n", &c);
    printf("Starting address of s = %p\n", s);

    // Sizes
    printf("Size of i = %ld\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Size of c = %ld\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Size of s = %ld\n", sizeof(char) * 6); // 5 characters and a null character
}
```

#### Heap

```
int main() {
    /* The following variables are pointers (i.e., they store addresses).
     * The addresses they hold are locations in the heap.
     * The size of the location pointed to by the pointer is 
       determined by the data type (int, char, etc.) */
    int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);

    // Place value(s) in the create memory locations
    *i = 4;
    *c = 'c';
    strcpy(s, "Hello");

    // Starting addresses (each variable i,c,s is an address)
    printf("Starting address of i = %p\n", i);
    printf("Starting address of c = %p\n", c);
    printf("Starting address of s = %p\n", s);

    // Sizes
    printf("Size of i = %ld\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Size of c = %ld\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Size of s = %ld\n", sizeof(char) * 6); // 5 characters and a null character
}
```

Comment: This gives neither the starting address nor the size, just some address IN the stack. In my case, I want to know the start address of a memory block with a known memory position in it. And your answer helps nothing there.